# Istio-check another host before routing

Tags: kubernetes, devops, istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

I want to configure istio gateways virtual service to check "auth-service" host before routing request to some hosts. Is there any option to configure this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Virtual Services or Destination Rules could check hosts.
VS just gets connections and through it to the DR

What type of check do you mean?

Comment: sorry i want to check token from header with my auth-service token then forward traffic

Comment: Try to ask question or queries to the author in the comment section instead of asking in the answer post itself

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @cursorrux I would like, but "You must have 50 reputation to comment"